# Run restore on working database. What happens?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, restore, zcat

What happens when I runned:

```
zcat /mnt/Postgres/restoreFile.gz | psql my_db
```

on the working database and after doing `ALTER TABLE` and other standard things there were problems with `duplicated keys`. When I stopped it and tried to insert into database then I got `duplicates key` error because of `sequences` and `constraints`. Seems like all data is in but what about the sequences. What really happend with that database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal Postgres backup consists of table design (like `create table`) and data (like `insert`) statements. If you run it twice, most design statements will fail. The `insert` statements would succeed in so far as the data definition allows for duplicate rows.

So restoring a database to a production server would typically result in a lot of duplicate rows in tables without a primary key.  Some design changes made after the backup (like changing the owner of a table) may be undone.